# Running .pyw file from Execute Process Task SSIS

Tags: python, excel, ssis, openpyxl

I'm trying to run this python script for renaming and saving an Excel sheet using SSIS Execute Process Task.

```
import openpyxl
import sys

filePath = sys.argv[1:]
print(filePath)
WorkBook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filePath)
print(WorkBook.sheetnames)
Worksheet = WorkBook.sheetnames[1];
print(Worksheet)
WorkBook[Worksheet].title = 'TransactionSummary'
WorkBook.save(r"C:\Users\*****\Downloads\WeeklyFileLoad\test.xlsx")
```

Below are the process details :

[image: execute process task]

I'm also using input variable from SSIS variable where excel file path is stored.And using `sys.argv` for getting this file path.

I'm not able to process this task due to this error :

```
    [Execute Process Task] Error:
 In Executing "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\pythonw.exe" "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\changingsheetname.py" at "", The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".
```

Comment: My understanding is that pythonw exits immediately whereas python will remain open until execution completes. The other thing that will likely come up is that the executable and the python file are both going to be in your folders. When you try to move this to a server, those paths won't be valid

Comment: I'm not familiar with pyhton, but what I read online, should you pass the variable FilePath value as the second argument to pythonw.exe (you can use the Expressions-tab to create arguments-string that contains script path and variable in quotes if any of them contain spaces)? I think StandardInputValue doesn't work in the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have spaces or special characters in arguments value. Please remove working directory value and keep only executable and arguments values those should be enough for running the script. Add double quotes in both arguments and executable strings in the SSIS package this will ignore the spaces between the strings of the file paths.

I have a small tip for you also if you are using python for running data process at end of the code please include

```
import sys
sys.exit(0)
```